# Firebase Hosting - Clear Cache

Tags: angular, firebase, caching, ionic3, firebase-hosting

Followed the Firebase tutorial to achieve Firebase Hosting. Hosted the app in console. But the problem is when I changed my html template and I re-deployed in Firebase console by running

```
ionic build --browser
```

and

```
firebase deploy
```

It's getting deployed but it's not updating in the mobile browser.

For example I have created a **ionic and angular** demo project. With the use of InAppBrowser able to connect with Firebase url

```
this.iab.create('https://xxx-xxxx.firebaseapp.com','_blank',"location=no,clearsessioncache=yes,clearcache=yes");
```

[image]Above Image without updated values

But when I tried to clear app cache in application settings. Then I am getting the output

[image]Above image with updated text. Expected result after uploading in firebase.

Below snippet tried to restrict cache.

```
1. clearsessioncache=yes,clearcache=yes given in InAppBrowser
```

2.In Firebase.json

```
"headers": [ {
  "source" : "**/*.@(eot|otf|ttf|ttc|woff|font.css)",
  "headers" : [ {
    "key" : "Access-Control-Allow-Origin",
    "value" : "*"
  } ]
}, {
  "source" : "**/*.@(jpg|jpeg|gif|png)",
  "headers" : [ {
    "key" : "Cache-Control",
    "value" : "max-age=7200"
  } ]
}, {
  "source" : "404.html",
  "headers" : [ {
    "key" : "Cache-Control",
    "value" : "max-age=300"
  } ]
} ],
"cleanUrls": true
```

I am not sure, the problem is with InAppBrowser or Default Browser or any configuration need to be done in ionic 3 app?

Comment: Your browser is loading the cached version in the browser. Reduce the cache-control of html files to few mins and set cache-control of static files very high.

Answer (score 0):

Try clearing all cache using:

```
  "headers": [
    {
      "source": "**",
      "headers": [
        {
          "key": "Cache-Control",
          "value": "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
```

Then add the css, image and 404 back afterwards.

Comment: This doesn't clear cache it says don't ever store it, and then honor the setting when you deploy.  My understanding is that deploy clears the cache itself.